# publish using mage (icon file)

Tags: icons, publish, mage

I've published an application using mage.
Everything is OK but the icon file is not showing.
I've used -if and -IconFile, but it didn't work.
The icon file is ico format.
Is there any point about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN resource in this link [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

you should Specify the full path to an .ICO icon file , but it doesn't work ;-)

I copied the icon file in the debug folder of project beside the application .exe file and I used only "filename.extension" after  -if or -IconFile commands like this:  -if icon.ico